# Laravel 5.6. File attributes not coming

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to add some attributes in my file input. Not in the browser that is not showing.

```
{!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'data-toggle'=>"modal", 'data-target'=>"#myModal"]) !!}
```

Output:

```
<input name="image" id="image" type="file">
```

Expected:

```
<input name="image" id="image" type="file" class="form-control" required="required" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what is the reason. When i am change `file` to `text` its working fine.

Now I just removed second parameter `null` for file(browse input file does not taken any value). Now It's working fine. Check my changes code:

```
{!! Form::file('image', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'data-toggle'=>"modal", 'data-target'=>"#myModal"]) !!}
```